# Where to download a vector file of Google's green android robot?

Tags: android

Does anyone know where to download a vector file of Google's green android robot?

The [Android Brand Guidelines page](http://www.android.com/branding.html) does not have a link to it!

Thankyou, Mel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.android.com/media/wallpaper/eps/android_logo.ps

more: http://www.android.com/media/

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old, but I had the same question.

The vectors I found weren't up to my standards (overlapping shapes, ungrouped paths, etc.) and they were mostly postscripts. You probably need an Illustrator file or SVG. I made a new one from a postscript version on the Android site. You can download the updated .ai or .svg here:

http://bit.ly/android_vector